# User defined class contructor and functions arent working, did i construct my class incorrectly?

Tags: c++, class

I'm not sure if I'm declaring the class correctly, please check out my code (for a card game) specifically where I make the constructor of the class and the three accessors. I get errors when I try to use the functions in the main, it says `Error  1   error C2228: left of '.get_rank_string' must have class/struct/union` for all three of the accessor functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>


using namespace std;

class Card 
{
public:
    Card();
    int get_rank() const;
    string get_suite_string() const;
    string get_rank_string() const;

private:
    int rank; //The rank represents the value of the card
    int suite; //The suite represents the type of card
};

Card::Card() //Default constructor setting rank to a random number between 1 and 14 and suite between 1 and 4
{
    rank = rand()%14;
    suite = rand()%5;
}

int Card::get_rank() const //returns the rank value of the rank of the card
{
    return rank;
}

string Card::get_rank_string() const //returns the name of the rank of the card 
{
    string x;
    if (rank == 1)
    {
        x = "Ace";
    }

    if (rank == 2)
    {
        x = "Two";
    }

    if (rank == 3)
    {
        x = "Three";
    }

    if (rank == 4)
    {
        x = "Four";
    }

    if (rank == 5)
    {
        x = "Five";
    }

    if (rank == 6)
    {
        x = "Six";
    }

    if (rank == 7)
    {
        x = "Seven";
    }

    if (rank == 8)
    {
        x = "Eight";
    }

    if (rank == 9)
    {
        x = "Nine";
    }

    if (rank == 10)
    {
        x = "Ten";
    }

    if (rank == 11)
    {
        x = "Jack";
    }

    if (rank == 12)
    {
        x = "Queen";
    }

    if (rank == 13)
    {
        x = "King";
    }

    return x;
}

string Card::get_suite_string() const
{
    string x;

    if (suite == 1)
    {
        x = "Clubs";
    }

    if (suite == 2)
    {
        x = "Hearts";
    }

    if (suite == 3)
    {
        x = "Diamonds";
    }

    if (suite == 4)
    {
        x = "Spades";
    }


    return x;
}

int main()
{

    string name;
    cout << "What is your name? ";
    getline(cin, name);

    int money;
    cout << "How much money would you like to start with? ";
    cin >> money;

    cout << endl << name << ", you have $" << money << "." << endl;

    int sum;

    while (sum > 0)
    {

    Card x();

    Card y();

    cout << "You got a " << x.get_rank_string() << " of " << x.get_suite_string() << "and a " << y.get_rank_string() << "of" << y.get_suite_string() << "." << endl;

    cout << "How much do you want to be the next card is in between? ";

    int bet;

    cin >> bet;

    Card z();

    if ((z.get_rank() > x.get_rank() && z.get_rank() < y.get_rank()) || (z.get_rank() < x.get_rank() && z.get_rank() > y.get_rank()))
    {
            cout << "YES! " << name << " you win $" << bet << endl;
            sum = money + bet;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "TOO BAD! " << name << " you lose $" << bet << endl;
        money - bet;
    }

    cout << name << ", you have $" << sum;

    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you so much!!! First time on stackoverflow and really suprised at how fast you guys answer these, feels good to have support! You guys are awesome (⌐ ͡■ ͜ʖ ͡■). – William Baires 8 mins ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Card x();` to `Card x;` to declare a default constructed variable.

Comment: Awesome, do yo know whats up with the other three functions though, they all show up as errors when i try to use them...

Comment: I was able to get a clean compile after removing the parentheses after x,y, and z.

Answer (score 1):

```
Card x();

Card y();
```

Does not actually declare two `Card`s named `x` and `y` but declares two functions named `x` and `y` that take nothing and return a `Card`.  To fix it just change it to:

```
Card x, y;
```

Answer (score 0):

you instantiate objects as:

```
Card x, y, z;
```

```
Card x();
Card y();
Card z();
```

is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the C++ parser interprets `Card x()` as a declaration of a function named `x` which returns `Card` and accepts no arguments.

Being interpreted as a function, invoking a method on it is not legal, that's why you get those errors. You are trying to do something

```
void foo();
foo.get_rank();
```

But the `.` operator expects a *class/union/struct* type on its left, while in your code it finds a function.

You must initialize the object in a different way:

```
Card x;
Card x{}; // C++11 only
Card x = Card();
```

Other things worth noticing: if you return a `string` you are returning by value, but in your case you have a string which makes no sense to change, you should return a `const string&`. In addition there is no need to use an if/else chain, you can use a switch statement or even better a lookup array, eg:

```
const string& get_suite_rank() {
  static const string suites[] = {"", "Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades"};
  return suites[suite];
}
```

Mind that the first element is empty because you start from index `1` for your suites instead that `0`.

Comment: Limited to if else statements so far, taking the intro course currently, but please elaborate on the return string, not sure if i did it correclty.